# Lines from a text file into a set (Python)

Tags: python, list, file, text, set

I am writing a program and I want to load lines from a text file into a set/list.

I want a user to input five numbers (separated by spacebar) my program will check how many times a user would win with these numbers. Lottery results are separated by commas if minimum 3 numbers match with lottery results on a given day my program will print all matching results something like:

```
"Three of your numbers match with:
01.27.1957 8,12,31,39,43,45
01.27.1957 8,12,31,39,43,45"

"Four of your numbers match with:
01.27.1957 8,12,31,39,43,45
01.27.1957 8,12,31,39,43,45

"Five of your numbers match with:
01.27.1957 8,12,31,39,43,45
01.27.1957 8,12,31,39,43,45"
```

My text file looks like this:

```
index date lottery_results

1. 01.27.1957 8,12,31,39,43,45
2. 02.03.1957 5,10,11,22,25,27
3. 02.10.1957 18,19,20,26,45,49
4. 02.17.1957 2,11,14,37,40,45
```

and so on...

I am stuck I don't even know how to start with this.

```
def read_data():
    results = open("dl.txt", 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime


file = open("dl.txt")

#user input
user_numbers = set(map(int, input('Enter numbers: ').split(',')))

for line in file:

    try:
        line = line.split()

        # converts the leading number (without the trailing '.')
        num = int(line[0][:-1])
        # converts from string to datetime object using the format
        date = datetime.strptime(line[1], '%d.%m.%Y')
        # creates a set of the coma separated numbers
        numbers = set(map(int, line[2].split(',')))
        # matches between the user input to the numbers
        matches = len(numbers & user_numbers)

        print(matches, 'of your number matches with', date.strptime('%d.%m.%Y'), 'whose numbers were', ', '.join(map(str, numbers)))

    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Don't use naked `except`s

Comment: It is not workig... after entering numbers this is what I see

[...]line 7, in <module>
    user_numbers = set(map(int, input('Enter numbers: ').split(',')))
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 3 10 39 24 49'

Comment: @yayusha i worte `split(',')`, means the user numbers should be separated by `,` and not space in the input. you can change it to `split()`

Comment: @Ureli Eli yeah, I know that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use readlines if your file is small. Few hundred lines are considered small.

```
>>> open('/tmp/data', 'r').readlines()
['line1\n', 'line2\n', 'line3\n']
```

See docs: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readlines#file.readlines

Comment: Well, my file includes almost 6k entries.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got this! That was so easy...

```
dl = open("dl.txt", "r")
for line in dl:
    line = line.split()
```

produces something like this

```
['5861.', '03.11.2016', '7,8,17,22,26,38']
```

Now I can navigate through this list. Thanks Uriel and Jay . :)